# eclipse import folder(s) (tfs)

Tags: eclipse, tfs

i have a folder which is inside a tfs source control.
It is not a Java Project or any Project at all. Just some files.

In my tfs plugin i can open source control explorer and navigate to this folder and edit those files (check out for edit is applied).

I find this very annoying and would like to have the folder show up in my Eclipse workspace explorer.

Is it possible to import this folder in Eclipse, to make them show up in my workspace (i don't want a copy of the folders in my workspace location, only a link to the diretory)?

Comment: What's the version control  are you using ? Git or TFVC?

Comment: Team foundation version control

Answer (score 0):

No, this can't be achieved.

> In Team Explorer Everywhere 2010, you cannot open a linked source code
> file. The Open button in a work item remains dimmed if you select a
> versioned item link.
>
> Source: [Open Projects from Version Control (Team
> Explorer Everywhere)](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/gg475875(v=vs.100).aspx)

To be a workaround, you may need to get a local copy of files from Source Control Explorer. And manage these files in the local and check the changes in source control. Detail steps please refer the [link from MSDN](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/gg475875(v=vs.100).aspx).